# selecting children from this (selected) div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a loop will create div as it needs to, all divs have the same class name, 
I have function

```
$(".divclassname").click(function () {
    var name = //I want to get the h1 text of the selected div the one the user Clicked on

    alert(name);
});
```

I tried many ways including

```
$("this > h1" ).text();
$( this > "h1" ).text();
$(this).children(h1);
$(this).children("h1").text();
```

I also assigned a class and tried this

```
 $(this).children(".h1class").text();
```

All results I got was empty. 
I am sorry I am begginer and the question might be quite easy forgive me. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: change `$(".divclassname").click(function () {` use `$(document).on('click','.divclassname',function () {`

Comment: The click-handler is allright, just try to select the first matching h1-element like: $(this).children("h1:first").text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need a delegate event handler to attach the click event:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.divclassname', function () {
 var name = $("h1", this).text();
});
```

and use `$("h1", this)` to find the `h1` within `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do what you need :

```
$(this).find("h1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this and works surely

```
$(document).on('click','.divclassname',function(){
     var name=$(this).find('h1').text();
    alert(name);
})
```